# ¿Como puedo agregar un filtro mediante un JComboBox en una JTable?

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo una consulta.
Deseo agregar un filtro a mi tabla haciendo uso de una lista de selección múltiple con un JComboBox, en este agregue la variable municipios.
Deseo filtrar solamente los datos contenidos en la columna MUNICIPIO_PRODUCTO, es decir si yo elijo en el JComboBox el municipio ALDANA, se muestre en mi tabla todos los datos que en su columna MUNICIPIO_PRODUCTO contengan este dato.

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class Index extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JTextField searchData;
    private JLabel txtLabel;
    private JTable showData;
    private JPanel secondaryPanel;
    private JScrollPane scroll_table;
    private JLabel showSearch;
    private JButton borrarButton;
    private JComboBox listData;
    static int columns;
    public Index() {
        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        setTitle("Consumos");
        setSize(1000, 800);
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
        conexion.conectar();
        String[] cabecera = {"PRODUCTO","CLIENTE","DOCUMENTO_IDENTIFICACION","NOMBRE_CONTRATO","NOMBRE_CLIENTE",
                "MUNICIPIO_PRODUCTO","BARRIO_PRODUCTO","SECTOR_OPERATIVO_PRODUCTO","COD_CICLO_CONSUMO,CICLO_CONSUMO",
                "RUTA","ORDEN_PREDIO","FECHA_INSTALACION_PRODUCTO","CATEGORIA","SUB_CATEGORIA","TRAFO_OPEN","MEDIDOR","CIRCUITO",
                "LATI_USU", "LONG_USU", "consumo_1", "consumo_2", "consumo_3", "consumo_4", "consumo_5", "consumo_6"};
        columns = Conexion.producto.size();

        Object[][] arreglo2 = new Object[columns][];
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            Object[] aux = {Conexion.producto.get(i),Conexion.cliente.get(i),Conexion.ID.get(i),Conexion.namContrato.get(i),
                    Conexion.namCliente.get(i),Conexion.mpioProducto.get(i),Conexion.barrioProducto.get(i),
                    Conexion.sectOpProducto.get(i),Conexion.codCicloConsumo.get(i),Conexion.cicloConsumo.get(i),
                    Conexion.ruta.get(i),Conexion.ordenPredio.get(i),Conexion.fechaInstProducto.get(i),Conexion.categoria.get(i),
                    Conexion.subCategoria.get(i),Conexion.trafo.get(i),Conexion.medidor.get(i),
                    Conexion.latitud.get(i),Conexion.longitud.get(i),Conexion.consumo_1.get(i),Conexion.consumo_2.get(i),
                    Conexion.consumo_3.get(i),Conexion.consumo_4.get(i),Conexion.consumo_5.get(i)};
            arreglo2[i] = aux;
        }
        showData.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(arreglo2, cabecera));
        String [] municipios ={"ALDANA","CONTADERO","CORDOBA","CUASPUD",
                "CUMBAL","FUNES","GUACHUCAL","GUALMATAN","ILES","IMUES",
                "IPIALES","POTOSI","PUERRES","PUPIALES"};
        listData.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(municipios));

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        searchData.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel obj = (DefaultTableModel) showData.getModel();
                TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> obj1 = new TableRowSorter<>(obj);
                showData.setRowSorter(obj1);
                obj1.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchData.getText()));
                super.keyReleased(e);
            }
        });

        borrarButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                searchData.setText(null);
            }
        });
        listData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Index Index = new Index();
    }

}
```

la conexion la realizo de esta manera:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Conexion {
    static ArrayList<Integer> producto = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> cliente = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> ID = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> namContrato = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> namCliente = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> mpioProducto = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> barrioProducto = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> sectOpProducto = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> codCicloConsumo = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> cicloConsumo = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> ruta = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> ordenPredio = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> fechaInstProducto = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> categoria = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> subCategoria = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> trafo = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> medidor = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> latitud = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> longitud = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> consumo_1 = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> consumo_2 = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> consumo_3 = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> consumo_4 = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> consumo_5 = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> consumo_6 = new ArrayList<>();

    String db = "consumos";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";
    String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection CX;

    public Conexion() {

    }

    public Connection conectar() {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            CX = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, password);
            Statement statement = CX.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from consumos");
            System.out.println("Se conecto a:" + db);
            while (rs.next()) {

                producto.add(rs.getInt("PRODUCTO"));
                cliente.add(rs.getInt("CLIENTE"));
                ID.add(rs.getString("DOCUMENTO_IDENTIFICACION"));
                namContrato.add(rs.getString("NOMBRE_CONTRATO"));
                namCliente.add(rs.getString("NOMBRE_CLIENTE"));
                mpioProducto.add(rs.getString("MUNICIPIO_PRODUCTO"));
                barrioProducto.add(rs.getString("BARRIO_PRODUCTO"));
                sectOpProducto.add(rs.getString("SECTOR_OPERATIVO_PRODUCTO"));
                codCicloConsumo.add(rs.getInt("COD_CICLO_CONSUMO"));
                cicloConsumo.add(rs.getString("CICLO_CONSUMO"));
                ruta.add(rs.getInt("RUTA"));
                ordenPredio.add(rs.getInt("ORDEN_PREDIO"));
                fechaInstProducto.add(rs.getString("ORDEN_PREDIO"));
                categoria.add(rs.getString("CATEGORIA"));
                subCategoria.add(rs.getString("SUB_CATEGORIA"));
                trafo.add(rs.getString("TRAFO_OPEN"));
                medidor.add(rs.getString("MEDIDOR"));
                latitud.add(rs.getString("LATI_USU"));
                longitud.add(rs.getString("LONG_USU"));
                consumo_1.add(rs.getInt("consumo_1"));
                consumo_2.add(rs.getInt("consumo_2"));
                consumo_3.add(rs.getInt("consumo_3"));
                consumo_4.add(rs.getInt("consumo_4"));
                consumo_5.add(rs.getInt("consumo_5"));
                consumo_6.add(rs.getInt("consumo_6"));



                //System.out.println(PRODUCTO + " | " + consumo_1 + " | " + consumo_2 + " | ");
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("No se conecto a: " + db);
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return CX;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        try {
            CX.close();
            System.out.println("Se desconecto a:" + db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("No se desconecto a: " + db);
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Trate de hacerlo de la forma:

```
        listData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                RowFilter.regexFilter(String.valueOf(municipios));
            }
        });
```

pero al estar ejecutando la ventana me sale el error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 27
[Ljava.lang.String;@6aac0cc1
```

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu problema sin detalles de tu clase Conexion. No obstante, indicarte que estás pasando como argumento al método regexFilter() un array, pero este método de [RowFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) espera como argumento una expresión regular.

Comment: Pregunta autocontenida, por favor. Sin enlaces externos. Ve a [edit] la pregunta. Sólo se necesita ver cómo estás armando la conexión

Comment: Intenta con `if (regularExpr == null || regularExpr.trim().isEmpty()) {
      table.setRowFilter(null);
    } else {`

Comment: Hola, te agradezco la ayuda, con esa parte del código ya logré filtrar haciendo uso del JComboBox, pero me filtra todos los valores contenidos en la tabla, como puedo hacer para filtrar una columna en especifico ?, es decir tengo las columnas PRODUCTO, CLIENTE, etc, deseo solamente buscar los valores en la columna MUNICIPIO.

Comment: @DanielRevelo tal vez sea momento de responderte a ti mismo la pregunta planteada y crear una nueva para las otras cosas que quieres y que no habías contemplado

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, la respuesta era tan sencilla como añadir un numero en el condicional obj1.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query, 5));